# MS-DOS application sending screen output to LPT printer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, printer, ms-dos, parallel-port

We have a MS-DOS application(coded in FoxPro), and recently had this glitch: the screen menu of the application without reason starts printing in an LPT Panasonic KX-1150 printer. It's a never ending print of all the screens of the application, as if the main output instead of sending it to the monitor, sends it to the printer! It creates a unnamed document with N/D pages and keeps printing forever.  We have to turn the printer off and then kill the document in the spool to stop it...

The printer is installed with a Generic/Text driver, and has happened to us both in WindowsXP and Win7.  What can this be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What changed? Have you tried using system restore to go back to a date before the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As it's a DOS application, then I can think of only 2 ways in which the output can be redirected:

1. Something has changed within the app itself. This is totally dependent on the app, and I cannot make any further comments.
2. The app is started with its output redirected, as in:

> APP > LPT1:

As you probably do not start the app from a command line with this redirection, you need to check the batch file that starts it. Right-click its icon and select EDIT, to open it in NotePad. If that looks normal, then my first suggestion is where your problem lies.